# Is the positive linear combinations of pseudoconvex functions pseudoconvex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $f_i$ be pseudoconvex functions for $i=1,\cdots, n$ and let $a_i$ be positive reals.

Is the function $f = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i$  pseudoconvex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is not true. I don't have a counterexample in my brain right now hence this is just a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_1(x) = -x^3 - x$ and $f_2(x) = 2x^3 + x$. The sum is $f(x) = x^3$ which is not pseudoconvex ($x=0$, $y=-1$ is a counterexample in the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function)).

Comment: Dear @LinAlg thanks for your answer.